# Modify text in items in SelectList

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I can't find a way to modify the text in each item on a SelectList to populate a dropdown menu. The values I'm populating the list with are from a database and are encrypted. I want to decrypt each item as it is loaded into the list and replace the encrypted text with the decrypted one.

This is an example of what I thought would work, But I still get the same results in the dropdown menu.

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        SelectList Types = new SelectList(db.Room_Type, "ID_Room_Type", "Name");
        foreach(SelectListItem i in Types)
        {

            i.Text = Util.Crypt.Decrypt(i.Text);    
        }

        ViewBag.Room_Type = Types;

        return View();
    }
```

Is there any permanent way to change and process this text as is being loaded?

Comment: could you instead of calling db.Room_Type, call something that does the decryption and returns the decrypted data?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you.. that's what I'm trying to do, I'm trying to decrypt the data on each item on the list.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
var l = new List<SelectListItem>();

foreach(var i in db.Room_Type)
{
    var sli = new SelectListItem();
    sli.Value = i.ID_Room_Type;
    sli.Text = Util.Crypt.Decrypt(i.Name);
    l.Add(sli);
}
SelectList Types = new SelectList(l);
```